# Android: How to find a row within an arrayadapter

Tags: android, position, android-arrayadapter

I need to search an arrayadapter for a value and position that row at the top of the screen.

I have a simple custom array adapter that is linked to a cursor.  The cursor finds 1000 records on average.  There is a point in the app that the user enters a piece of information.  From that I can find the item in the database using a quick database lookup.

I then know that the item is in my arrayadapter.  I need to find the position in the adapter and move that item to the top of the screen.

How can I find where in the adapter this value is?  I know the data exists in the found set, but how do I find this value in that found set and put it at the top of the screen?

I know how to position the screen once I find it in the adapter, just not an efficient way to find it.  I am currently looping through the array until I find the correct row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as you said you're looping through the array in linear fashion. You could build a HashMap which maps keys to an int of your position - so lookups are done in constant time.